# ListView items. Handle images with huge height

Tags: android, image, listview

I have listview items with simple View inside, and i need to display image with huge height in it. I have cache system which can split large image into smaller ones.

Question:

What is the best way to handle displaying large images in one listview item?
Sure i can add some views to item at runtime(10 view 1000px height for example), but i think that i will get out of memory.

My point is to make my app display image like 9gag app.

**9gag app**

[image]

**9gag view hierarchy**

[image]

Comment: Actualy i have idea to split one listview item with huge image into some items with part of image in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not load large bitmaps to memory  consider loading a smaller version into memory, set inSampleSize to true in your BitmapFactory.Options object. For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384.

[Use these common guidelines for loading large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I`m using inSampleSize, but when i have source image 608x20640, output image is 304*10320. It`s still too much :(

Comment: I think normal view in mobile phones have height of average 1000px So there is no need in loading   10320px heighted image into user screen.

Comment: Use calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) in the above link to find the apt inSampleSize for your need or set it to 8 or 16

Comment: >I think normal view in mobile phones have height of average 1000px
That`s why i want to split source image into smaller one. Big images after resizing look not realy good.